# Failing to get line numbers with Boost stacktrace + backtrace

Tags: c++, boost, stack-trace, backtrace, boost-stacktrace

I'm trying to reproduce the first and simplest [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html#stacktrace.getting_started.how_to_print_current_call_stack) in the Boost Stacktrace documentation.

```
#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE

#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void bar(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        // ... somewhere inside the `bar(int)` function that is called recursively:
        std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();
        return;
    }
    bar(n-1);
}

int main() {
    bar(4);
}
```

And am only having partial success: I'm getting the function name, but not the line:

```
 0# bar(int) in ./plain_vanilla
 1# bar(int) in ./plain_vanilla
 2# bar(int) in ./plain_vanilla
 3# bar(int) in ./plain_vanilla
 4# bar(int) in ./plain_vanilla
 5# main in ./plain_vanilla
 6# __libc_start_main at ../csu/libc-start.c:342
 7# _start in ./plain_vanilla
```

(my source file is named `plain_vanilla.cpp` and my executable is `plain_vanilla`.) I'm using Boost 1.73.0, which I built, on a Devuan 3.0 GNU/Linux. libbacktrace is installed (it's part of glibc) and I'm linking against it.

Is this more likely something I've done wrong, or is it an actual bug in the library?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/issues/97#event-10202288981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get more information in the stack track uses a debug build.
For GCC compile a project with the flag `-g` or `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.