# boost::stacktrace fails to provide line number

Tags: c++, boost, boost-stacktrace

I'm having issues with getting the line number of a stack frame provided by boost::stacktrace. When printing the task with `boost::stacktrace::to_string` it prints the line number but when calling  `source_line()` it returns 0.

Example:

```
auto frame = boost::stacktrace::stacktrace()[0];
std::cout << frame << std::endl;
std::cout << frame.source_file() << ":" << frame.source_line();
```

```
Outut:
foo::bar() at /some/path/to/file/file.cc:24
/some/path/to/file/file.cc:
```

Is there any solution or do I have to do some manual string manipulation to get the line number?

Comment: What backend have you selected? What is the platform? Did you include debug information? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html

Comment: ADDR2LINE, Ubuntu and no I guess.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973197/failing-to-get-line-numbers-with-boost-stacktrace-backtrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same behaviour on Ubuntu 18.04 with full debug info.

Using

```
strace -f -e execve,clone,fork,waitpid ./sotest
```

Shows that the command being executed is

```
[pid  5972] execve("/usr/bin/addr2line", ["/usr/bin/addr2line", "-e", "./sotest", "0x000055EC1854F7FF"], 0x7fff8e99bdd8 /* 82 vars */) = 0
```

Indeed, manually checking

```
/usr/bin/addr2line -e ./sotest 0x000055EC1854F7FF
```

Prints

```
??:0
```

I've got no idea why this is, as the debug info is very much there (even at `-g -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer`):

```
$ file sotest
sotest: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=53bae8898d711d1946ac4cb805740b11aa1cc045, with debug_info, not stripped
```

#### Workaround?

I had more success with the `libbacktrace` backend

```
#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_BACKTRACE
```

Printing

```
$ ./sotest 
foo::bar() at /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:8
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:8
```

Of course this requires linking the backtrace library. but this appears to be part of the standard Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Just a thought; do your by any chance have address sanitizer or ub sanitizer enabled? I do and it might be a factor. Currently underway so can't check.

Comment: addr2line has some limitations https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/issues/97